# wrapping GPIO.add_event_detect into a try except stops it from running

Tags: gpio, python

I have a basic system with a normally closed switch I need to monitor.
If I run the program with the following setup, it works:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("waiting for redunancy trigger")
    GPIO.add_event_detect(pinRedunancyTrigger,
                          GPIO.FALLING,
                          callback=fnTripRedundancy,
                          bouncetime=200)
```

However, if I wrap the same statement into a 'try/except' (in order to add the GPIO.cleanup() to the end).  It doesn't trip when when the switch opens and the GPIO falls.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("waiting for redunancy trigger")
        GPIO.add_event_detect(pinRedunancyTrigger,
                          GPIO.FALLING,
                          callback=fnTripRedundancy,
                          bouncetime=200)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('keyboard killed the process')
    except:
        print ('something else wiggity happened')
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why the 'try' doesn't allow the edge_detection to register.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I've also just tried to take the main code chunk that runs under the **main** logic check, and created itself in its own function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   fn_runmain()
```

then inside the fn_runmain() put the same try/except block as above.
EXACT same result.

The function fn_runmain runs properly without the try/except inside it, but does *not* when I add the try/except.

Comment: Same issue, GPIO version 0.6.0a3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the [changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) for 0.6.1 of the RPi.GPIO library:

> Issue 118 - add_event_detect sometimes gives runtime error with unpriv user

I was having the exact same problem and it disappears if I run my python program as superuser.

instead of this:

```
$ python myprog.py  # fails most of the time
```

try this:

```
$ sudo python myprog.py  # succeeds
```